# Wizard vs magician in Italian

Tags: vocabulary

In English there is:

- wizard = a guy in a fairy tale who can change a human into an animal
- magician = real person who performs magic tricks

What are their translations into Italian?

I have found two words: "mago m, stregone m".

Hypothesis: wizard = stregone, magician = mago.

Am I right?

Thank you.

Comment: A magician is a “person with magical powers” too, not just a conjuror.

Answer (score 9):

You are mainly right; but in Italian "mago" is quite generic and could be applied to both cases.
You could translate *magician =  prestigiatore*, while keeping *wizard = mago*.

Comment: “Magician” (in the sense of “congiuror”) can also be translated as *illusionista*.

Comment: yes, "conjurer" = "illusionista", "prestigiatore"; while (IMO) the correct translation of "stregone" would be "sorcerer"

Answer (score 2):

English has a lot of terms for "magical user", some traditional and some introduced by fantasy literature and games:

- wizard
- sorcerer
- warlock
- magician
- illusionist
- conjurer
- summoner
- medium
- clairvoyant

and more.

In Italian there are less options. These are the ones that I can think of, with the appropriate pairing with English when there is one:

- *mago* (wizard): generic term for magic user, it applies also to the "classic" idea of magic user (Merlin was a *mago*).
- *stregone* (wizard / sorcerer): male version of *strega* (witch). It has a *slightly* more esoterical meaning than wizard (*stregoni* are usually "darker" and more mysterious than *maghi*).
- *prestigiatore* / *illusionista* (magician / illusionist): not a magic user, but rather one that does tricks (like at a fair). The former is more specialized in sleight of hand tricks, the latter is more about creating misperceptions.
- *evocatore* / *invocatore* (summoner + conjurer): someone who can use magic to materialize creatures or objects. There is no strict distinction as in English between the two cases.
- *medium* (medium): someone who can perceive / communicate with spirits (not necessarily of the dead).
- *veggente* (clairvoyant): Someone who can see across time (future) or space (afar). It does not includes prophecies: *profeta* (prophet) is more appropriate in that case.

Two more things worth mentioning: there is no direct translation for "warlock" when used in the meaning of someone who uses magic specialized in combat (fantasy meaning).

There is one specific Italian term, *iettatore*, who is someone who has the power to curse people with the *malocchio*, which will bring misfortune.

Comment: Considerando che ne hai elencati 9 in inglese e 8 in italiano, non mi sembra che l'italiano stia messo tanto male, pure non considerando incantatore, taumaturgo, negromante, fattucchiere, sciamano, maliardo... (mi sono aiutato in parte con http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mago_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/).

Comment: Fair point, anche se quelli che hai citato (maliardo a parte?) hanno cmq tutti una controparte in inglese. Magari e' solo una mia impressione che ci sia meno tassonomia in italiano :)

Comment: Aggiungerei warlock alle parole tradotte con stregone